# Why is my "List<String>" being interpreted as "List<String>?"

Tags: kotlin

```kotlin
class Example(private val childrenByParent: HashMap<String, List<String>>) {

    private val parents: List<String> = childrenByParent.keys.toList()

    fun getChildrenCount(parentPosition: Int): Int {
        return childrenByParent[parents[parentPosition]].size 
        // error, recommends using "?." or "!!"
    }
}
```

The compiler won't let me call `size` directly but I don't understand why. There are no nullable types in sight.

If I let the compiler infer the type by doing this:

```kotlin
val infer = childrenByParent[parents[parentPosition]]
```

I can see that it assumes it's a `List<String>?`

It seems that I'm quite confused about nullability still. Would appreciate some help. I have a feeling I'm doing something incredibly dumb, but after some searching and testing I failed at fixing this.

I would like for this function to not use `?.` or even worse, `!!`. Is it possible? At least, using `HashMap` and `List<String>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HashMap.get(Object)` returns `null` when there is no element matching the key you provided, so its return type is effectively nullable, regardless of whether the values are or not.

So unfortunately you have to account for the case in which the key doesn't exist, so your choices are either implementing a case where it doesn't, or just declaring it as non-null with `!!` if you are sure the key exists.

Otherwise you can use `HashMap.containsKey(String)` to ensure the key exists and then you can be confident that using `!!` on the value won't result in a `NullPointerException`.

However as @gidds pointed out, this is not naturally thread-safe without some more work, so it might be best to just handle the case of the key not being in the map. Also I cannot actually think of many cases where you could be sure that key exists, in which a `Map` is the most appropriate data structure to use.

---

Also, even though this is not the case here, remember that nullability is just a feature of Kotlin, so when using some classes originally written in Java, whether an element is nullable or not is unknown. The IDE will usually represent this as `Type!` where the single `!` tells you it is a platform type.

Comment: ...regardless of whether the value type is nullable. I think that's the part the OP didn't realize.

Comment: Note that if there's the slightest possibility of the map being used by multiple threads, then calling `containsKey()` followed by `get()` or `[]` introduces a [time-of-check to time-of-use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) race condition, and can break if another thread removes the entry in between.